# List all tables with zero rows within all databases

Tags: sql-server

I want to list all the empty tables with zero rows, my main problem is that I don't know how to make it possible on every databases.

```
DECLARE @select varchar(MAX)
SET @select =
'
SELECT 
 DB_NAME() ''Database''
,T.NAME ''Table''
,P.rows ''RowCounts''
FROM 
sys.tables T
LEFT JOIN
sys.partitions P ON T.object_id = P.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE 
T.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
P.rows = 0
GROUP BY 
T.Name,
P.Rows
ORDER BY 
T.Name
'
USE X1
EXEC (@select)

USE X2
EXEC (@select)
```

The X1 and X2 should be the databases, but I don't know how to transform it to be dynamic.

Comment: Try with **sp_msforeachdb** undocumented system stored procedure to iterate database by database. It should be very careful when using the **UnDocumented** objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without executing the whole statement once per DB, by concatenating the queries together into a single query. I'm going to shamelessly plagiarise [Larnu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65593927/14868997) query and show you how to do that:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = 

(SELECT STRING_AGG(
    CAST( N'SELECT N' AS nvarchar(max)) +
    QUOTENAME(name,'''') +
    N' AS DatabaseName,
    T.NAME AS TableName,
    P.rows AS [RowCount]
FROM ' +
    QUOTENAME(name) +
    N'.sys.tables T
LEFT JOIN ' +
    QUOTENAME(name) +
    N'.sys.partitions P ON T.object_id = P.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE T.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
      P.rows = 0
GROUP BY T.Name,
         P.Rows'

    , NCHAR(10) + N' UNION ALL ' + NCHAR(10)
) + NCHAR(10) + N'ORDER BY Name;'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4  -- exclude this line if you want system DBs also
);

--PRINT @SQL; --Uncomment to debug
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: I had to complete the on Ln21 with an extra closing parenthesis, but what is more interesting that I received the following error:

Msg 9829, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

Comment: Hum, how many DBs do you have? Need to cast to NVARCHAR(max). Fixed

Comment: About 20 of them, now I got this error:

Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The STRING_AGG function requires 2 argument(s).
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 26
Must declare the scalar variable "@SQL".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 27
Must declare the scalar variable "@SQL".

Comment: Strange the query get through over the 8th db and right after it dies:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 41

and so on until the Line 191

Comment: FYI, `N'...' + QUOTENAME(name) + N' AS DatabaseName,` should be `N'... N' + QUOTENAME(name,'''') + N' AS DatabaseName,` (Yes that is an `N` in the literal string too). The above would give `SELECT [master] AS DatabaseName`, which isn't valid syntax. You want `SELECT N'master' AS DatabaseName`.

Comment: Though unlikely, `N'SELECT N''' AS nvarchar(max)) +
    QUOTENAME(name) +
    N'''` won't work if someone has a poorly named database like `[Mc'Fadden]`. Make use of `QUOTENAME`'s second parameter to define the delimit identifier.

Comment: As for the error, that's actually because you have an `ORDER BY` prior to the `UNION ALL` being completed. an `ORDER BY` has to go at the very end of the statement.

Comment: Arghh. Can you fix those, I'm unsure about `QUOTENAME` I'll defer to you on that.

Answer (score 2):

. I'm going to shamelessly use my own proc, [`sp_foreachdatabase`](https://wp.larnu.uk/a-cursor-free-version-of-sp_msforeachdb/) here (as many have documented, the undocumented `sp_msforeachdb` has "features", and can be unreliable) to run the statement against each of the user databases on the server, and pass a "normally" written  statement to it, with the exception of using `&` as a replacement character to inject the database's name as an `nvarchar`.

```sql
USE master;
GO
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @Command nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT & AS DatabaseName, --Don''t use single quotes for aliases, it''s confusing as they are for literal strings
       T.NAME AS TableName,
       P.rows AS [RowCount]
FROM  sys.tables T
LEFT JOIN sys.partitions P ON T.object_id = P.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE T.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
      P.rows = 0
GROUP BY T.Name,
         P.Rows
ORDER BY T.Name;';

EXEC sp_foreachdatabase @Command = @SQL, @Skip_System = 1, @Auto_Use = 1, @Command_Run = @Command OUTPUT;
```

If you want to put all the data into a single dataset, then you'll need to create a table first, `INSERT` the data, and then `SELECT` it back:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @Command nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE @PreCommand nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE TABLE #EmptyTables (DatabaseName sysname, TableName sysname, [RowCount] int);',
        @PostCommand nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT DatabaseName, TableName, [Rowcount] FROM #EmptyTables;';
SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO #EmptyTables(DatabaseName, TableName, [Rowcount])
SELECT & AS DatabaseName, --Don''t use single quotes for aliases, it''s confusing as they are for literal strings
       T.NAME AS TableName,
       P.rows AS [RowCount]
FROM  sys.tables T
LEFT JOIN sys.partitions P ON T.object_id = P.OBJECT_ID 
WHERE T.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND
      P.rows = 0
GROUP BY T.Name,
         P.Rows
ORDER BY T.Name;';

EXEC sp_foreachdatabase @Command = @SQL, @Skip_System = 1, @Auto_Use = 1, @Pre_Command = @PreCommand, @Post_Command = @PostCommand, @Command_Run = @Command OUTPUT;
```

*For completeness, the definition of `sp_foreachdatabase` from the linked article:*

```sql
USE master;
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE [name] = N'objectlist')
    CREATE TYPE dbo.objectlist AS table ([name] sysname);
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC sp_foreachdatabase @Command nvarchar(MAX),
                                        @Delimit_Character nchar(1) = N'?', --Character to be replaced with a delimit identified version of the datbaase name I.e. [master]
                                        @Quote_Character nchar(1) = N'&', --Character to be replaced with a single quoted (') version of the datbaase name I.e. 'master'
                                        @Skip_System bit = 0, --Omits master, msdb, tempdb and model. Ignored if @Database_List has data.
                                        @Skip_User bit = 0, --Omits all user databases. Ignored if @Database_List has data.
                                        @Database_List dbo.objectlist READONLY, --If @Skip_System and @Skip_User equal 1, and this is empty, an error will be thrown
                                        @Auto_Use bit = 0, --Automatically starts each command agaisnt a database with a USE
                                        @Exit_On_Error bit = 1, --If an error is occurs against a single database, the command will still be run against the remainder. Otherwise everything is rolled back
                                                                --This does not effect the @Pre_Command and @Post_Command statements
                                        @Pre_Command nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --Command to run before @Command. Does not use Character Replacements. Run against master DB.
                                        @Post_Command nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --Command to run after @Command. Does not use Character Replacements. Run against master DB.
                                        @Command_Run nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT  --Returns the generated and replaced command, for trouble shooting
AS BEGIN
 
    --Do some checking of passed values first
    --Check that @Skip_System, @Skip_User aren't both 0 or that @Database_List has some rows
    IF (@Skip_System = 1 AND @Skip_User = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Database_List))
        THROW 62401, N'System and User databases cannot be skipped if a Database List is not supplied.', 16;
         
    IF @Delimit_Character IS NULL OR @Delimit_Character = ''
        THROW 62402, N'@Delimit_Character cannot have a value of NULL or ''''.', 16;

    IF @Quote_Character IS NULL OR @Quote_Character = ''
        THROW 62403, N'@Quote_Character cannot have a value of NULL or ''''.', 16; 
 
    IF @Skip_User IS NULL
        THROW 62404, N'@Skip_User cannot have a value of NULL.', 16;
 
    IF @Skip_System IS NULL
        THROW 62405, N'@Skip_System cannot have a value of NULL.', 16;
 
    IF @Auto_Use IS NULL
        PRINT N'@Auto_Use has a value of NULL. Behaviour will be as if the value is 0.';
 
    DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    DECLARE @RC int;
 
    --Add the Pre Command to the batch
    SET @Command_Run = ISNULL(N'/* --- Pre Command Begin. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'USE master;' + @CRLF + @CRLF + @Pre_Command + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Pre Command End. --- */', N'');
 
    --Get the databases we need to deal with
    --As @Database_List might be empty and it's READONLY, and we're going to do the command in database_id order we need another variable.
    DECLARE @DBs table (database_id int,
                        database_name sysname);
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Database_List)
        INSERT INTO @DBs (database_id,database_name)
        SELECT d.database_id,
               d.[name]
        FROM sys.databases d
             JOIN @Database_List DL ON d.[name] = DL.[name];
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @DBs (database_id,database_name)
        SELECT d.database_id,
               d.[name]
        FROM sys.databases d
        WHERE (d.database_id <= 4 AND @Skip_System = 0) OR (d.database_id > 4 AND @Skip_User = 0);
 
    SET @Command_Run = @Command_Run + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                       N'/* --- Begin command for each database. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                       CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'--Turning XACT_ABORT off due to @Exit_On_Error parameter' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'SET XACT_ABORT OFF;' + @CRLF + N'DECLARE @Error nvarchar(4000);' ELSE N'SET XACT_ABORT ON;' END +
                       (SELECT @CRLF + @CRLF + 
                               N'/* --- Running @Command against database ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''') + N'. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               CASE WHEN @Auto_Use = 1 THEN N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name) + N';' + @CRLF + @CRLF ELSE N'' END +
                               N'BEGIN TRY' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               REPLACE(REPLACE(@Command, @Delimit_Character, QUOTENAME(DB.database_name)),@Quote_Character, 'N' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''')) + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                               'END TRY' + @CRLF +
                               N'BEGIN CATCH' + @CRLF +
                               CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'    SET @Error = N''The following error occured during the batch, but has been skipped:'' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + ' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'                 N''Msg '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_NUMBER()) + '', Level '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_SEVERITY()) + '', State '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_STATE()) + '', Line '' + CONVERT(nvarchar(6),ERROR_LINE()) + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +' + @CRLF + 
                                                                 N'                 ERROR_MESSAGE();' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'    PRINT @Error;' + @CRLF +
                                                                 N'    SET @RC = ERROR_NUMBER();'
                                                            ELSE N'    THROW;'
                               END + @CRLF +
                               N'END CATCH;' + @CRLF +
                               N'/* --- Completed @Command against database ' + QUOTENAME(DB.database_name,'''') + N'. --- */'
                        FROM @DBs DB
                        FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)') + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                        CASE WHEN @Exit_On_Error = 0 THEN N'--Turning XACT_ABORT back on due to @Exit_On_Error parameter' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'SET XACT_ABORT ON;' ELSE N'' END;
 
    SET @Command_Run = @Command_Run + ISNULL(@CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Post Command Begin. --- */' + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'USE master;' + @CRLF + @CRLF + @Post_Command + @CRLF + @CRLF + N'/* --- Post Command End. --- */', N'');
 
    EXEC sp_executesql @Command_Run, N'@RC int OUTPUT', @RC = @RC;

    SET @RC = ISNULL(@RC, 0);
    RETURN @RC;
 
END;
GO
```

Comment: Go ahead... OP wanted this query for each DB, that's what I gave is it not?

Comment: XY problem. He doesn't need `foreachdb` at all.

Comment: You realise that your answer is doing it for each database, @Charlieface ... Right..? And that is what the OP wants. But again, I am not using `(sp_ms)foreachdb`. I explicitly state I am not. Ther's no [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) here. The OP hasn't stated they need Y, when they actually need X.

Comment: I was just using shorthand for " `sp_foreachdatabase` by Larnu", which I fully agree is better than the real thing for executing per DB. But you don't need to execute this on every DB separately and insert into temp table. My answer does not do that, it is a single query with a single resultset.

Comment: @Charlieface , yours does, however, execute against *every* database... Including the system ones. `SELECT ... FROM master.sys.tables .... UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM model.sys.tables` is performing a statement against every database...

Comment: It's not executing a **new** statement against **each** one and inserting into a temp table. It's a single query, far more efficient and easier to maintain. Have added the check for system DBs though

Comment: Do you have any evidence that a large amount of `UNION ALL` queries against multiple databases is more efficient than multiple statements, @Charlieface ? (Note, that my solution does *not* use a `CURSOR` which *would* be far slower.)

Comment: Insert into @DB, and an insert on each query into #EmptyTables, plus a select back out, plus the rest of the overhead? I don't even know what the question is. Your `sp_foreachdatabase` is lovely and I would prob make use of it, but here it's a hammer for a nut. Have upvoted you though

Comment: Hi Guys, 

Thank you both for your comments, actually I am thinking about to have a cursor command, I'll have the original select (as in the original post) and then put it into cursor like this: 

USE [The name of the database which will be changed by the cursor]
EXEC @select 

Is it possible? I am quite newbie about the cursors.

Comment: A `CURSOR` would actually be the slowest as well, mpataki . Both my and @Charlieface use a set based solution; far faster.